# What's the best way to write an app with multiple timers?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, timer, stopwatch

Basically I am writing a timer app with many timers that count up, not down. Only 2 of them are gonna be active. One is chosen by the user, the other is the `total` timer. The user can change which timer is active at any time, automatically stopping the other timers (except the `total` timer). It will only show down to seconds so (HH:MM:SS).

Right now I am using an `int` for each counter and increment it via a `Winforms` `Timer` (1 second interval). In the tick event for each timer I am using:

```
this.TimeDisplay.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds).ToString();
```

This works but I am wondering if this is the best way? I know there are many timers in .NET, so which one would be the most lightweight, easy on the computer resources? I will leave this app running 24/7 so that's why I don't want it to hog the CPU or accumulate memory constantly.

The timers will be reset by the user in 24-30 hours.

Should I avoid using `Winforms` `Timer`, but rely on `Stopwatch` or one of the other timers available in .NET?

Not sure which one is best suited for this.

Comment: Are the timers of your own design or are they some of the built in ones?  If you have built them yourself you could simply make a property that you set if it's the active timer and have it ignore the stop signal if it's the active one.

Comment: Thanks Jared, no I just use regular labels that are oversized.

Comment: What ever is simplest to code and works.  You are not going to be hogging anything if all you are doing is incrementing an int once a second.

Comment: Why do you need to increment an int every second? Timer's are not guaranteed to fire at the interval you specify, the OS will simple _try_ to fire the events at those intervals. A more accurate, less resource consuming way would be to simply record the time when the user _starts a timer_. If you need to display this, simply tell your timer to display the diff of timer start time vs now.  This will give much greater accuracy as well. Or have I misunderstood your requirements? This way, a single timer and list of start times can service all timers.

Comment: Thanks, the timers will be started and stopped though, how would I record all these? The total I can always do, Now - globalStart, but for instance timer1 can start and then the user can start timer2, thus stopping timer1, and so on, how would you track these?

Comment: @Joan, for an example pretend you only need to track one timer that can be started and stopped. Create a simple struct that records start and stop times. The latter is nullable so that no end time means the timer has not been stopped.  If a user _pauses_ a timer, add an end time to the struct. If the user _resumes_ the timer, add a new struct to the list with the start time populated. You can now accurately track not only the seconds the timer was active using a simple linq statement, but also exactly when they were started/stopped. Now add this list to another list for multiple timers.

Comment: Take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945058/timer-efficiency/ it may be worth to read. I also recommend to study http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/faq.html as similar ready to use system and http://www.drdobbs.com/embedded-systems/an-embedded-single-timer-wheel/217800350 for timer wheel algorithm. Timer wheel is not directly applicable but you can borrow idea.